# Modify 3D numpy array in slices in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a complex numpy array **signal** with dimensions [10,1000,50000]
I need to modify this array in slices. This is done in a for loop:

```
for k in range(signal.shape[2]):
    signal[:,:,k] = myfunction(signal[:,:,k], constant1, constant2, constant5=constant5, constant6=constant6)
```

I optimized myfunction as much as possible. When I run the script it takes quite some time but only uses 1 of 24 CPU's.

The code can not be rewritten to perform myfunction on the entire array with numpy.

Therefore I want to speed up my code with parallel computing.
There seem to many different approach for parallel computing in python.
Which one seems to be the best for my problem? And how can I implement it?

Comment: In general, when you work with numpy, you want to avoid having any loops in python code and instead find the correct numpy functions which will process the whole array in one go. Then it is up to numpy to handle parallelization.

Comment: What is `myfunction`?

Comment: If the parameters to the function are calculated from the slice, then you could tell numpy to do that for each slice.

Comment: Ok guys, first thanks for all the feedback. I can not perform calculations on the entire array to retrieve the parameters for each slice. I need to perform myfunction independently on each slice. myfunction is too complex. Thanks again

Comment: Use dask. Is designed to parallelize numpy operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Joblib` provides easy execution for such 'embarrassingly-parallel' tasks:

```
import numpy as np

# Initialize array and define function 
np_array = np.random.rand(100,100,100)
my_function = lambda x: x / np.sum(x)

# Option 1: Loop over array and apply function
serial_result = np_array.copy()
for i in range(np_array.shape[2]):
    serial_result[:,:,i] = my_function(np_array[:,:,i])
```

Now using parallel execution with `joblib`:

```
# Option 2: Parallel execution
# ... Apply function in Parallel 
from joblib import delayed, parallel
sub_arrays = Parallel(n_jobs=6)(                            # Use 6 cores 
                      delayed(my_function)(np_array[:,:,i]) # Apply my_function 
                      for i in range(np_array.shape[2]))    # For each 3rd dimension

# ... Concatenate the list of returned arrays
parallel_results = np.stack(sub_arrays, axis=2)

# Compare results 
np.equal(serial_result, parallel_results).all() # True
```

Comment: The code works great. But I tried to apply it to a 4D array, too, by accessing np_array[:,i,:,:]. However, I receive the error message "output array is read-only" in one of the joblib functions